CosmosDB copy - how to delete jobs
I have created many "Faulted" jobs, I don't know these jobs will incur costs or not. So I want to delete these jobs. But I failed to find the way to do that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-container-copy
If possible, I want to delete these jobs, too many information when I type az cosmosdb copy list.
And tell me the cost of these offline jobs.

These jobs will not incur any cost, jobs have an expiry of 3 months and after that they will be deleted, since they don't incur a cost, no need to manually delete them.
